# which definition is better?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int array[2][2] = {{1,100},{1000,10000}};

    int *pointer    = array;
    int *ppointer   = &array;
    int *pppointer  = array[0];
    int *ppppointer = &array[0];

    printf("%d\n",*pointer);
    printf("%d\n",*ppointer);
    printf("%d\n",*pppointer);
    printf("%d\n",*ppppointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Four pointers are point to the first element of array.
which definition shown above is better?
And I don't known why the same value to array and &array?

Comment: Why did you tag the question with [tag:c] and [tag:c++]? Those are **different languages*. Please remove the unnecessary tag (most likely [tag:c++]).

Comment: A good practice to see the difference, as pointed by many people here, is to print the pointer address via `%p`. Then you can increment the pointer by `1` and look at how many bytes the pointer has been shifted :)

Comment: @GradGuy: Well, in this example the declared pointers will be shifted identically, since the distinction between the pointer types is already lost at the point of initialization.

Comment: @AndreyT: Agreed. I was more thinking of something like `printf("ptr = %p\tshifted_ptr = %p\n", (void*)array, (void*)(array+1))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only reason all for of your definitions compile is that your C compiler is too permitting when it comes to pointer type conversions. If you use some switches that make it more pedantic in this regard, it should immediately tell you that only the third initialization is valid, while the rest are erroneous.

In most contexts (with a few exceptions) when array of type `T[N]` is used in an expression, it "decays" (gets implicitly converted) to pointer type `T *` - a pointer that points to its first element. In other words, in such contexts for any array `A`, the `A` expression is equivalent to `&A[0]`. The only contexts where array type decay does not occur are unary `&` operator, `sizeof` operator and string literal used as an initializer for a `char` array.

In your example `array` is a value of `int [2][2]` type. When used on the right-hand side of initialization it decays to pointer type `int (*)[2]`. For this reason this is invalid

```
int *pointer    = array;
```

The right-hand side is `int (*)[2]`, while the left-hand side is `int *`. These are different pointer types. You can't initialize one with the other.

The

```
int *ppppointer = &array[0];
```

is exactly equivalent to the previous one: the right-hand side produces a value of `int (*)[2]` type. It is invalid for the very same reason.

The `&array` expression produces a pointer of `int (*)[2][2]` type. Again, for this reason

```
int *ppointer   = &array;
```

is invalid.

The only valid initialization yo have in your example is

```
int *pppointer  = array[0];
```

`array[0]` is an expression of `int [2]` type, which decays to `int *` type - the same type that you have on the left-hand side.

In other words there's no question of which one "better" here. Only one of your initialization is valid, others are illegal. The valid initialization can also be written as

```
int *pppointer  = &array[0][0];
```

for the reasons I described above. Now, which right-hand side is "better" (`array[0]` or `&array[0][0]`) is a matter of your personal preference.

---

In order to make your other initializations valid, the pointers should be declared as follows

```
int (*pointer)[2]     = array;
int (*ppointer)[2][2] = &array;
int (*ppppointer)[2]  = &array[0];
```

but such pointers will have different semantics from an `int *` pointer. And you apparently need `int *` specifically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!But how do you know what exactly the type is on the right-hand side?I mean is there any methods to figure out the type?I m really confuse on that.......

Answer (score 2):

Only the third actually does the right thing. All other three are invalid C++ and cause warnings in my C compiler. It is often preferable to write C that is also valid C++, because on some platforms the `C++` compiler is the also recommended compiler for C also (MSVC). This also makes it easier to include C code in a C++ project without significant build-system fiddling.

Why does your compiler complain about about 1, 2 and 4? Neither of the expressions on the right hand side have the right type to be converted to `int*`.

1. `array` has type `int[2][2]` it can be converted to `int(*)[2]`, not `int*`
2. `&array` is a pointer to an `int[2][2]`
3. `array[x]` has actually type `int*`
4. `&array[x]` has type `int**`

Comment: He is asking about the C language, not C++

Comment: @DevinGund C++ compatability is often important and in this case C++'s stricter type system simply points errors on what C grudgingly allows.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *pointer    = array;     //Incorrect
int *ppointer   = &array;    //Incorrect
int *pppointer  = array[0];  //Correct
int *ppppointer = &array[0]; //Incorrect
```

That's the short version.
Now for the reasons.

The first pointer is incorrect, because you're assigning 'array' (which is a pointer without any further specification)...but not one of int, but one of int *[]

The second pointer is incorrect, since you'd be assigning the address of the pointer...essentially the address of the variable, which holds the pointer to the data.

The third one is correct, because you get a pointer to an int array, regardless of size.

The fourth one is incorrect, since you're copying the address of the first array.
That makes it an int **, and not a int *.

Sorry for the many edits...I must be tired.

Comment: @akappa Okay, I overlooked the crucial point of it being two-dimensional...meh, I must be tired. Please remove the downvote, I'll remove the answer. A more capable one has been posted already.

Comment: @akappa Thank you very much. Also for pointing out this silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

> $ cat decls.c

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[2][2] = {{1,100},{1000,10000}};
    int *pointer    = array;
    int *ppointer   = &array;
    int *pppointer  = array[0];
    int *ppppointer = &array[0];
}
```

> $ clang decls.c -Wall -o decls

```
decls.c:4:7: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an
      expression of type 'int [2][2]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        int *pointer    = array;
             ^            ~~~~~
decls.c:5:7: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an
      expression of type 'int (*)[2][2]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        int *ppointer   = &array;
             ^            ~~~~~~
decls.c:7:7: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'int *' with an
      expression of type 'int (*)[2]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        int *ppppointer = &array[0];
             ^            ~~~~~~~~~
```

So only the third declaration is correct.

Slightly long answer: when you declare something in C, you declare it using an **expression** which, when evaluated, gives you the type at the left.

So, if you have a `char name[][]`, then it means that when you have `name[2][3]`, you get a `char`. This works the other way around: let `A = name[3]`; how can you can get a `char` out of `A`? By doing `A[2]`, so `A` is a `char *`.

This is why only the third declaration is correct: because the declaring expression at the left and the expression at the right both have the same type.

Comment: a warning doesn't mean the code is incorrect. It just mean that the coder should pay attention and check if it is exactly what he intended to do.

Comment: Which is nearly never the case. When you really want to screw up the type system, you usually put there explicit casts.

Comment: @lcfseth: your POV in the matter is, at best, naïve. You see the type system as a useless formalism because, "in the bare metal", types doesn't exists. This is the worse way of looking at programming languages. A programming language is a self-contained formalism, with a syntax and an associated semantic. It has nothing to do with assemblers and things like that. In the wonderful world of C languages, expressions have a given type and the things at the left and at the right of the equal sign **must** have the same types. Compilers are usually not so restrictive, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

None of them are correct (third one will not give error but I don't think it will be the value the poster want).

It should be:

```
int ** pointer1    = array;
int ** pointer2   = &array;        //This one is wrong
int ** pointer3  = array[0];      //This one is not correct in this case
int * ppointer3  = array[0];
int ** pointer4 = &array[0];
int * pointer5 = &array[0][0];
```

I prefer the first one and last one.

If it is a 1-dimensional array, I would prefer the first one, because it shows the fact that array is basically pointer. If it is a multi-dimensional array, I would use the last one (because it only needs dereference once to get the value, but be careful about the index: for example if you want to get 1000, you will need to use `pointer5[2]` instead of `pointer5[1][1]`

Comment: "I don't think it will be the value the poster want" does not implies it is "not correct". And BTW, why do you think it isn't what the OP wants?

Comment: @akappa Assumption. It is not good to assume, but when insufficient info is given, some assumptions have to be made, just like boss is never clear what he want, but we have to figure out based on our assumption.

Answer (score -1):

They are all equivalent.

&array is the address of the array, which start at the same position as its first element and therefor &array = &array[0]

array is an array but in some case, it can decay into a pointer to its first element, that is why array = &array = &array[0]

As for 
    `int *pppointer  = array[0];`

my first impression is that this should be wrong. may be someone else can explain.

Update: My guess is that array is considered as a pointer by the compiler here giving:

`int *pppointer  = (&array)[0] = array[0]`

Comment: They are equivalent only concerning the address they point to, but not concerning their type.

Comment: True :) But types means nothing once the code is compiled :). There is no difference in terms of performances.

Comment: @lcfseth: The code will simply not compile in any pedantic C compiler. The code is erroneous. It is too early to talk about "performances" if the code is not compilable.

Comment: It does compile. I ofc tried it before I answered :) It is only refuted by some compiler and mostly C++, but no C. This is correct C code, even if the specs has changed a little since I learned C  (about 15years ago :p).

Comment: @lcfseth But type is important e.g. for pointer arithmetics, including index access. If you have the type wrong, your results will be wrong as well.

Answer (score -2):

So, you have an array within an array. So the variable "array" is actually a pointer to another pointer.

So if you say:

```
int *pointer = array;
```

You've got a type mismatch. `*pointer` is a pointer to an int, but `array` is a pointer to another pointer.

When you say:

```
int *ppointer = &array;
```

You've still got a type mismatch. &array gives us the address of the pointer to a pointer, which we could only assign to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer.

When you say:

```
int *pppointer = array[0];
```

This is correct. Square brackets *dereference* the array variable. So `array[0]` actually refers to a pointer to an int, which matches up with `*pppointer`'s type.

When you say:

```
int *ppppointer = &array[0];
```

So, we're kind of back to where we started here. `array[0]` is a pointer to an int, so `&array[0]` is the address of a pointer to an int, which we could only assign to a pointer to a pointer to an int.

So in the end, the third one is the only one that is actually valid. However, I personally think a better way to accomplish this would be:

```
int *pointer = *array;
```

Comment: `array` is not a "pointer to another pointer". `array` is a 2D array. If it decays, it decays to `int (*)[2]` - a pointer to a 1D array, not a pointer to pointer.